# "indefined selection console.log(data[])"

Tags: javascript, api

I can recover my api but I cannot recover firstname in my object people, do you have a solution?

here my code for select l'object people :

```
console.log(data['people']);
```

and i want select firstname in my object people

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your people object is an array so, to get the firstname value you need to either loop in this array (with foreach or map) and then use .firstname, or you can just specify an entry

so you can do :

```
data['people'][0].firstname
```

or

```
data['people'].forEach(element => {
    element.firstname
});
```

Answer (score -1):

can you loop the array by using map.

```
data['people'].map((item, index) => {


console.log(item.firstname)
})
```

Comment: `.map()` has a very specific usage. If you are simply trying to loop, use a `.forEach()`. (Or just a regular for-loop.)

Comment: can we use this

for(var x = 0; data['people'].length > x; x++){
 data['people'][x].firstname
}